# How to calculate Sharepoint users for licensing?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, licensing

How to calculate Sharepoint users for licensing?

Which tool to use to calculate the Sharepoint users for licensing purposes.

Maybe there PowerShell script?

Or use Reports Web Analytics?

Or stupid to count users in groups?

Answer (score 2):

You can Use the  Microsoft Assessment and Planning Toolkit (MAP)to count the license CAL in SharePoint 2010. You can see below PDF, how to configure it.

[A Guide to Assessing SharePoint Server Licensing](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/8/9/68964284-864d-4a6d-aed9-f2c1f8f23e14/Assessing_SharePoint_Server_Licensing.pdf)

or You can think about this 3rd party tool: http://www.flexerasoftware.com/enterprise/products/software-license-management/flexnet-manager-suite-enterprises/