# how to find out the project server device cal and project server user cal? in the current sharepoint 2010 environment

Tags: 2010

I am trying to find out the Project server device cal and project server user cal from the current sharepoint 2010 environment. If someone can help me how to find that numbers from the environment like do we have any scripts??

Comment: check this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/175084/how-to-calculate-sharepoint-users-for-licensing